# MSChart - Can 2 legends be automatically stacked on the right?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mschart

I'm dynamically building a chart in C# (.Net Framework 3.5 so the first release of MSChart).  The chart includes a series identifier legend and a second legend of custom items (a table of properties used in the data).

By default, the two legends (A & B) appear side by side with the main chart area (X) like this: X B A.  This causes wasted space below the legends and reduces the size of the chart.

I've tried options I could find, but even if I put B to center or far, it's still between X and A.  Is there a way to have them position themselves automatically on the right in a vertical stack?  So B would be automatically positioned under A?  Or would I have to use manual positioning for them?

---

Edit: Forgot to mention an addition (potentially critical) detail: I'm not displaying the chart in a form, but calling the `SaveImage()` function to write a PNG.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{
    setLegendPosition();
}

private void chart1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setLegendPosition();
}

private void setLegendPosition()
{
    chart1.Refresh()
    Legend L1 = chart1.Legends[legendOneNameOrIndex];
    Legend L2 = chart1.Legends[legendTwoNameOrIndex];

    L2.Position = new ElementPosition(L1.Position.X, L1.Position.Y + L1.Position.Height, 
                                      L1.Position.Width, L1.Position.Height);
}
```

This positions the 2nd legend right under the first one.

You could add `1 (%)` to the calculated value for a little spacing...

If you want to place it to the middle of the height you could replace the calculated `Y` position with `50`, ie fixed `50%`.

And if you want a fixed space of `n pixels` between the two `Legends` simply calculate the space like this:

```
int pixels = 20;
float space = 100f / chart1.Height * pixels;
```

and add it to the `Y-Value`!

Also call `setLegendPosition();` after creating the `Legend`..

**Update** I had expected the modified question would not post any problems, but I took a while to get it right..:

- The setting up of the chart should be called from the `Form.Shown` event.
- The `setLegendPosition` needs a `chart.Refresh()` at the start.
- Instead of using the simple `chart1.SaveImage` I had to resort to the `chart1.DrawToBitmap` method.

  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(chart1.ClientSize.Width, chart1.ClientSize.Height))
  {
      chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart1.ClientRectangle);
      bmp.Save(yourfilename, ImageFormat.Png);

  }

Here are the two results from `SaveImage`  and `DrawToBitmap`:

[image: saveimage]![image: drawtobitmap]

Comment: This is great!  Except for one detail I didn't mention in my question, I'm not displaying it in a WinForms control but directly writing a PNG file.  Your code works great if I display the chart in a form and resize it after it's displayed.  If it's not displayed on a resize (through code for PNG writing or on the initial display of the form), when the Resize event gets called L1's position is all `0`s.

Comment: That's some awesome dedication to help.  Thank you!